# Structural Changes - Utilizing R-package strucchange to Test for 0 vs. l or l vs l+1 breaks

Tags: r, regression, time-series, change-point

I'm using the R-package `strucchange` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/strucchange/strucchange.pdf) to test for structural changes in different time series.

As far as I understood the method `sctest()` in the strucchange package (to perform the tests for structural change) has implemented the double maximum test ("`maxBB`") to test for an undefined number of structural changes against no change.

Bai and Perron (e.g. [2003 - Computation and analysis of multiple structural change models](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/jae.659)) extended this approach for F-statistics to tests for 0 vs. a fixed number of breaks l and also l vs. l + 1 breaks.

Is it possible to utilize the strucchange packages to run these tests as well and get the corresponding p values and test statistics?